# Shutdown spring boot application from multiple applications which are running on single tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to shutdown spring boot application programmatically from multiple applications running on single tomcat server without stopping tomcat.

I have searched over Google found couple of solutions like

```
System.exit(0)
```

and

```
SpringbootApplication.exit()
```

causing shutting down tomcat. I don't want to shutdown tomcat. Just the particular application.

How can I do that.. programmatically is there any way to do this.

Pls help!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the actuator.

Add this dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add these properties in your yml / properties file

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

With this in place, you can hit this rest endpoint to shutdown the application

```
http://host:port/actuator/shutdown
```

This is a **POST** call. If you are using spring security in your application, then you might want to make a few adjustments to allow this endpoint to go through. you can invoke post call using curl like

```
curl -X POST http://host:port/actuator/shutdown
```

Comment: that's nice to know that actuator have such endpoint. But actuator is not recommended or must be secured endpoints in case application is public +1.

Comment: Actuators are meant exactly for this purpose. To manage the application from outside(But of course with necessary security contraints in place). Hence they are grouped under "management".

Comment: Indeed!Point I wanted to make -  actuator is very powerful so should be used with complete caution and security.

Comment: Actually I want to do it at some point if condition meet it will shutdown automatically.

Comment: yes. You can call this rest endpoint programatically using any rest client library(RestTemplate) when your codition is met. Without more info cannot really suggest

Comment: + 1, upvoted it, the actuator can run in separate URL, so irrespective of the application is public or not, it's access can be restricted to local IP

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by registering an endpoint(highly secure though) to which your applications can send request for shutdown and you can code endpoint as below:

```
         ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(YourApplicationClassName.class, args);
        int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(ctx, new ExitCodeGenerator() {
            @Override
            public int getExitCode() {
                // no errors
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

**Security -**  I would recommend that if you want to send termination signal to an app through other apps, you can use app token that uniquely identify the apps priviledged to shutdown your application.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to **kill the app process**.

First, the application has to write its PID to a file (shutdown.pid):

```
SpringApplicationBuilder app = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
  .web(WebApplicationType.NONE);
app.build().addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter("./bin/shutdown.pid"));
app.run();
```

Then you can create a file (shutdown.bat) and add this line:

```
kill $(cat ./bin/shutdown.pid)
```

The execution of shutdown.bat extracts the Process ID from the shutdown.pid file and uses the kill command to terminate the Boot application.

ps: stolen from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown).

Comment: That won't work with a deployed application. That only works for a standalone application.